# Matching predictions to groundtruths for multiple object detection

Tags: python, computer-vision, object-detection, bounding-box

What is the best way to match pred_bbox to gt_bbox in a multiple object detection problem?

right now, I'm matching based on the maximum score (confidence score) and filtering out matches with IoU < threshold (threshold=0.1).

The problem is when two or more objects are in close proximity, I can lose matches with much better IoU and a good score, or miss gt because it pred matches to a different gt.

for example:

Let's assume a frame has two CAR objects in close proximity, and the model has only two detections with class CAR

```
det-1 score=0.7   
IoU(det-1, gt-1)=0.8  
IoU(det-1, gt-2)=0.05

det-2 score=0.9  
IoU(det-2, gt-1)=0.4  
IoU(det-2, gt-2)=0.5
```

In the example above, the results are:
(gt-1, det-2) matching pair (det-2 is tp) because it has the maximum score
gt-2 miss-detection (fn)
det-1 fp

my desired result is:
(gt-1, det-1) matching pair, det-1 is tp
(gt-2, det-2) matching pair, det-2 is tp

I probably can do it based only on IoU, but is there a known solution to this problem?

Should I experiment with different matching approaches? based on IoU only, match-based on two levels - IoU and then confidence score, a new score combines IoU and objectness?

Thank you!